# Problem centering text in the middle of the checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to center text in the middle of the checkbox, but the text is on top.

I will leave the full code here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<head>
    <style>
        input {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            padding-left: 25px;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        input {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"><span>text</span></input>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the text is not centered, what can I do?

Comment: What do you mean from both relative and absolute position for a single input? Is there a reason to use position styles instead of simple inline elements?

Comment: I used inline to leave the text on the same line, I don't know if that's it..

Comment: If you remove `top: 6px;` It will be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<head>
    <style>
        .w3-check,
        .w3-radio {
            vertical-align: top;
            top: unset;
        }
        .w3-check span,
        .w3-radio span {
           vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"><span>text</span></input>
</body>

</html>
```